# How do I start off a password validation code with def and to have a T/F return in Python?

Tags: python

I’m a newbie in Python. I’m supposed to write a user defined function starting with def for a password validation code, but I have no idea where to start...

The requirements for the password

- Minimum 10 characters in length
- Minimum of 3 digits and 3 special characters
- Minimum of 1 uppercase and 1 lowercase letter

It states that my function should return a Boolean “True” / “False” value according to the conditions met;  True if all are met and False if any of the above are not met.

Any idea how to write this code? Thank you so much!

Here is my current code:

```
def passwordValidity(password):

digit, special = 0,0

special_char =["!","@","#","%","^","$","&","*","(",")",".","?",",","/"\
               "=","+","-","_","[","]",">","<","|"] 
validity = True
for i in range(len(password)):
if len(password) <= 6: 
    val = False
    
elif not password[i].isdigit():
    digit += 1

elif not password[i].isspecial():
    val = False
      
elif not any(char.isupper() for char in password):
    val = False
      
elif not any(char.islower() for char in password):
    val = False
if val: 
    return val 

print(val)
```

I do not know how to continue from here; is there a special method for counting special chars like isdigit, isalpha etc. And how am I supposed to tell the code to only accept password that has minimum 3 digits/special chars? Thank you

Comment: Homework questions are ok as long as you show your existing effort and ask for help on a specific issue. This is not a code writing service.

Comment: Welcome! Sorry, but what you ask isn't our thing around here. Please review [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). "Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow. You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a specific question about your implementation. Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials or documentation, and is not a way to have research, design or coding work done for you.

Comment: @Selcuk  So sorry! Thank you so much for the advice, I have added my code that I've currently written so far. I do not know where to continue from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
elif not password[i].isdigit():
    digit += 1
```

That is a good start to count the digits. But it is not used to return True or False.

Do a similar thing with special:

```
elif password[i] in special_char:
    special += 1
```

At the end of the function, you could do:

```
val = val and digit > 2 and special > 2
```

before returning val (without the if).

However, I think you will also need to debug the code, as there might be a 'not' too much.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for replying! I've edited my code according to what you said; I'm getting an error at the start of my code during the if len(password) part, is there anything wrong with my code that I have to fix? Thanks!

Comment: @oompaloompa Please clarify "an error". Edit your question and include the whole error message with full traceback.

Comment: I'm not offended (why would I be?). This is simply a clarification request. We didn't know what error you were getting. Now that we know that it's an indentation error: Indentation matters in Python. You should indent everything below that `for` line up to `print` and probably follow an introductory Python tutorial.

Comment: @Selcuk Thank you so much, have a nice day! :)